# Как убрать промежуток между Titlebar и Menubar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlayout, qmenubar

Как убрать некрасивый отступ между `Titlebar` и `Menu`?

[image]

```
import sys
import PyQt5

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, Qt

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, 
    HBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QWidget, QAction, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSizeGrip, QMenuBar

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        #self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.menu_bar = QMenuBar()
        self.menu_bar.setStyleSheet("""
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #23272A;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-left: 4px;
        """)
        self.menu_bar.addMenu('&Файл')
        #self.menu_bar.show()

        self.title_bar = TitleBar(self)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.title_bar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.menu_bar)

        self.layout.addStretch(-1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addStretch(-1)

        self.status_bar = StatusBar(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.status_bar)
        self.setFixedSize(800,400)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #2c2f33;
        """)
        self.setWindowTitle('Code Maker')


class TitleBar(QWidget):
    height = 35

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        #print(self.parent.width())
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.title = QLabel("Code Maker")
        self.title.setFixedHeight(self.height)
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)

        self.title.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #23272a;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: white;
        """)

        self.closeButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_close)
        self.closeButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #DC143C;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.maxButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.maxButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_maximize)
        self.maxButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #32CD32;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.hideButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.hideButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_hide)
        self.hideButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #FFFF00;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.layout.addWidget(self.hideButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.maxButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False

        self.maximaze = False

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(TitleBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.parent.move(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement))
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False

    def on_click_close(self):
        sys.exit()

    def on_click_maximize(self):
        self.maximaze = not self.maximaze
        #print(self.maximaze)

        if self.maximaze:    self.parent.setWindowState(Qt.WindowNoState)
        if not self.maximaze:
            self.parent.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)

    def on_click_hide(self):
        self.parent.showMinimized()

class StatusBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StatusBar, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.label = QLabel("Status bar...")
        self.label.setFixedHeight(24)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #23272a;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            color: white;
        """)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.show()

    def showMessage(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    mw.status_bar.showMessage("Hello world!")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QLayout Class
>
> spacing : int
>
> Это свойство содержит интервал между виджетами внутри макета

Смотрите здесь:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#spacing-prop

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QPoint, Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout,
                             QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QWidget, QAction,
                             QLabel, QSizeGrip, QMenuBar)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class TitleBar(QWidget):
    height = 35

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.title = QLabel("Code Maker")
        self.title.setFixedHeight(self.height)
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)

        self.title.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #23272a;  /* 23272a   #f00*/
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: white;
        """)

        self.closeButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_close)
        self.closeButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #DC143C;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.maxButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.maxButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_maximize)
        self.maxButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #32CD32;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.hideButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.hideButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_hide)
        self.hideButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #FFFF00;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.layout.addWidget(self.hideButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.maxButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False
        self.maximaze = False

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(TitleBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.parent.move(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement))
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False

    def on_click_close(self):
        sys.exit()

    def on_click_maximize(self):
        self.maximaze = not self.maximaze
        if self.maximaze:    self.parent.setWindowState(Qt.WindowNoState)
        if not self.maximaze:
            self.parent.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)

    def on_click_hide(self):
        self.parent.showMinimized()


class StatusBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StatusBar, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.showMessage("Hello world!")

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Status bar...")
        self.label.setFixedHeight(24)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #23272a;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            color: white;
        """)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
#        self.show()

    def showMessage(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)
        

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(800, 400)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)        
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #2c2f33;   
        """)
        self.setWindowTitle('Code Maker')
        
        self.title_bar = TitleBar(self) 

        self.menu_bar = QMenuBar()
        self.menu_bar.setStyleSheet("""
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #23272A;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-left: 4px;
        """)
        self.menu_bar.addMenu('&Файл')

        self.status_bar = StatusBar(self)

        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title_bar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.menu_bar)
        self.layout.addStretch(1)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.status_bar)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)                               # +++ <<<=====================
        
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вынесите настройки стилей в отдельную переменную или файл
и вашу программу будет легче читать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]