# Как изменить стиль окна в PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss

У меня в программах всегда такие окна

[image: -]

Как мне сделать в PyQt5 например вот такое окно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста ваш пример и расскажите лучше, `такое окно` это какой окно? Что в нем особенного ?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html

Comment: Знаешь стандартное окно виндовс7? Немного прозрачное, а как меня сделать окно(там где крестик, сворачивание окна) сделать например другой цвет, как на картинке

Comment: Да я знаю стандартное окно виндовс7.  То что вы спрашиваете, уже обсуждалось. Посмотрите здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855760/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0/855884#855884  и  здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997577/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-titlebar-%d0%b8-menubar/997641#997641.

Comment: кратко как это сделать: убрать заголовок окна и рисовать его самостоятельно